# Java: Sorting a map

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to hold scores for players for a highscore.

A typical input :

```
map.put(p1, 9);
map.put(p2, 7);
map.put(p3, 9);
```

Now I need a way of ordering the map so to be able to see the order of players based on their scores. However, I've tried just sorting based on the value of the map but then I lose cases where two or more players have the same score.

Is a map even the best way to do this or should I try a different data type? All I need is a way to order players based on their scores.

Comment: Any reason why the score itself is not "part of" the player?

Comment: @fge it could be reasonable if a single player could have a score in more than one game.

Comment: Then why not a `Map<Integer, List<Player>>` for each game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would keep the score for the player within the `Player` object itself. Then you can just create a list of the players, and order it with a `Comparator<Player>` implementation that orders by scores - either deliberately making it "highest score first" or using `Collections.reverseOrder` to reverse the sort order of a "lower score first" comparator.

Comment: Makes much more sense than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A map might be a good way to store the scores; it depends on what else you need to use it for in your program. For example, it would be good if you need to store a separate score for more than one type of game, while using some of the same player objects.

Whether or not storing scores in a map is the best solution for you, you can still use the scores in the map to sort a list of players. Create an implementation of [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that compares two players by comparing the scores present in the map. ([`Integer.compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) might be helpful for this.) Then, create a new list of all the players you want to sort. Finally, use [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) to sort this list.